# How to use redirector output in powershell with mbsacli

Tags: powershell

I am trying to run this with Start-Process but it doesn't seem to run as it is.  Many thanks in advance.

Using cmd /C works:-

```
cmd /C ("$([char]34)" + "C:\Program Files\MBSA\bin\mbsacli.exe" + "$([char]34)" + " /xmlout /wi /nvc /nd /catalog " + "$([char]34)" + "C:\Program Files\MBSA\db\wsusscn2.cab" + "$([char]34)" + " /unicode > " + "$([char]34)" + "C:\Program Files\MBSA\result.xml" + "$([char]34)")
```

Using Start-Process doesn't works:-

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MBSA\bin\mbsacli.exe" -ArgumentList (" /xmlout /wi /nvc /nd /catalog " + $([char]34) + "C:\Program Files\MBSA\db\wsusscn2.cab" + $([char]34) + " /unicode > " + $([char]34) + "C:\Program Files\MBSA\result.xml" + "$([char]34)") -Wait -PassThru
```

Comment: `>` is a command prompt shell instruction, it's not an argument to mbsacli.exe. If you're not using the command prompt, you'll have to get the results in PowerShell and pipe them to `Set-Content` or similar to save them to an output file. You can have a double quote in a string by 1) escaping it with another double quote `"""xyz"""`, 2) escaping it with PowerShell escape character, which is a backtick `"\`"xyz\`""`, 3) by using single quotes around the string `'"xyz"'`. Why are you using Start-Process at all - I don't know mbsacli, but Robocopy with /parameters runs directly from PowerShell

Comment: I need the command to complete before proceeding to the next command. So need the -wait parameters thus using the start-process.  Not sure if I can use any other command as I am new to powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use -RedirectStandardOutput followed by filepath

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MBSA\bin\mbsacli.exe" -ArgumentList (" /xmlout /wi /nvc /nd /catalog " + $([char]34) + "C:\Program Files\MBSA\db\wsusscn2.cab" + $([char]34) + " /unicode" ) -Wait -PassThru -RedirectStandardOutput "C:\Program Files\MBSA\result.xml"
```

and instead of $([char]34) you can use double quotes directly if you are enclosing it with single quotes ,like this:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\MBSA\bin\mbsacli.exe" -ArgumentList ' /xmlout /wi /nvc /nd /catalog "C:\Program Files\MBSA\db\wsusscn2.cab" /unicode' -Wait -PassThru -RedirectStandardOutput "C:\Program Files\MBSA\result.xml"
```